# Multiple commands in sshpass

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, sshpass

Is there a way to use the multiple commands in `sshpass`, I tried with difference combinations but it throws error.

```
$ sudo sshpass -p $password ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$ipaddress << EOF
  command_one
  command_two
  command_three
EOF
```

What is the correct and exact command, please provide me with an example if possible.

Comment: Your example should work.  sshpass is not really relevant.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If you want separate file for commands: sshpass -p $password ssh $username@$ipaddress -t "$(cat ssh-init.inc.sh)"

Answer (score 7):

Your solution works with or without sshpass, if it's not working for you there is likely something else wrong.

**Also note you should always quote every variable.**

*Additionally you shouldn't disable stricthostkeychecking lightly.  If your host key is changing frequently your server is probably compromised*

Here are some ways to accomplish your goal though:

---

Using a command separator (`;`, `&&`, `||`)

```
sshpass -p "$password" ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "$username@ipaddress" 'command_one; command_two; command_three'
```

---

Using a here-doc (Single quote EOF to have any variables/command substitutions expand on the remote host):

```
sshpass -p "$password" ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "$username@ipaddress" <<EOF
  command_one
  command_two
  command_three
EOF
```

---

Using a separate file:

**file.sh**

```
command_one
command_two
command_three
```

Then execute like this:

```
cat file.sh | sshpass -p "$password" ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "$username@ipaddress"
```

---

Using an ssh tunnel:

```
sshpass -p "$password" ssh -f -L 3306:localhost:3306 "$username@ipaddress" sleep 300 # This will open a tunnel to the remote host and hold it open for 5 minutes
ssh -T "$username@ipaddress" 'command_one'
ssh -T "$username@ipaddress" 'command_two'
ssh -T "$username@ipaddress" 'command_three'
```

---

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this:

```
$ sudo sshpass -p $password ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$ipaddress << EOF
command_one;
command_two;
command_three;
EOF
```

I did the above and it works fine.