# Execute bash pipeline using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to execute a `ssh` command executing a `bash` command on a remote host. My problem is that I want to pipe the result of another command inside of the execution.

```
ssh -i ~/keys/pem_key.pem ec2-user@url.com "sudo docker logs $(docker ps | grep 'test' | awk '{print$1}')"
```

The part of the command:

```
$(docker ps | grep 'test' | awk '{print$1}')
```

is not executed inside of execution.

Any way how this can be achieved?

Comment: @guest Thanks. Yes, the problem is with escaping the dollar, but in both parts. `\$(docker ps | grep 'test' | awk '{print\$1}')`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/459923/237982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following:

```
ssh -i ~/keys/pem_key.pem ec2-user@url.com "sudo docker logs \$(docker ps | grep 'test' | awk '{print\$1}')"
```

Comment: If I try `ssh -i ~/keys/pem_key.pem ec2-user@url.com 'sudo docker logs $(docker ps | grep \'test\' | awk \'{print$1}\')'` seems that is not working

Comment: @david It won't work with single quotes, try double quotes as suggested by david.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is possible to get a command that needs complicated quoting passed through `ssh` argument(s) to the remote, it is often simpler to supply it as *input* instead:

```
 ssh -i ~/keys/pem_key.pem ec2-user@url.com <<'EOF'
 sudo docker logs $(docker ps | grep 'test' | awk '{print$1}')
 EOF
```

Note the here-doc delimiter `'EOF'` is quoted; this causes the input to be passed without any change to the remote, which executes it. It can actually be any string that isn't in the input; `EOF` is just a customary and easy-to-type value. And you can use `<<\EOF` or `<<"EOF"` instead if you prefer.

Also note this particular case could be simplified to:

```
 ssh -i ~/keys/pem_key.pem ec2-user@url.com <<'EOF'
 sudo docker logs $(docker ps | awk '/test/{print$1}')
 EOF
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for..... thanks :)

Comment: Very useful, how to u know  here-doc delimiter 'EOF' need to be quoted?